How does spark structured streaming work with compacted kafka topics?
I have a compact Kafka topic that I just starting consuming messages from starting at the earliest offset. My spark job does not seem to be writing any data (it is writing parquet files to AWS S3) at the moment but i can see that the checkpoints are updating and my executors are completing tasks. My topic has the current configuration:
{
  "cleanup.policy": "compact",
  "retention.ms": -1,
  "delete.retention.ms": 20000000,
  "compression.type": "snappy",
  "segment.bytes": 100000000,
  "segments.ms": 100000000,
}

My spark application is consuming from the topic starting at the earliest offset (there are 32 partitions and the current offset sum is 48 Billion)
My questions are:

does spark start from the earliest clean segment of the log and work its way up to the active segment?
as the application work its way through the dirty segments and encounter keys with existing records, how does spark perform the upsert/reconcile this?
how does spark handle tombstone markers? What happens if the tombstone marker is deleted due to the topic's delete.retention.ms policy? How will this affect the data that spark is writing to S3?

However, if I start consuming from the latest starting offset i can see the paruqet files being created. What is actually happening under the hood here?

Does this answer your question? Cleanup Policy:Compact/Delete and log.retention
